# Drop-down menu automatically redirects to parent link on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a drop-down navigation menu on my website that works fine. However on mobile devices, when a user taps any menu item, they are shown the submenu for a fraction of a second and then automatically redirected to the parent link. I would like a function where tapping the parent link the first time opens the submenu, and a second tap redirects the user to the parent link. I would like something as explained here : http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly

However, I just want the double-tap feature. I have implemented the plug-in but it still doesn't work for me :/  My drop-down menu is coded with HTML and CSS.

```html
<ul class = "dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Here is my CSS below. I tried to use the jQuery plug-in doubleTapToGo.js from the link above, but it would not work.

```css
ul.dropdown,
ul.dropdown li,
ul.dropdown ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size:11px;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}


ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover {
 position: relative;
 cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown ul {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
 float: left;
 border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
 padding-bottom:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px; 
}


ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: could you show us the jquery code your using to show/hide the items?

Comment: Just edited to show my CSS

Comment: As far as I know, drop down menus are bad UX design for mobile devices as there isnt really a 'hover' action, which is usually how drop-downs work. And then a double click action can be confusing/misleading. Why should the user have to press a link twice to use it? I guess its just my opinion... Perhaps there is a solution wiht jquery mobile? I would use responsive design to display a different menu style.